# Expression for linear operator transforming $x^n\to n!x^{-n}$?

Tags: operator-theory, power-series

I wonder, is there an expression for a linear operator that transforms $x^n\to n!x^{-n}$, particularly, affecting this way power series?

I mean, can it be expressed via some kind of integrals, derivatives, etc? What about the inverse operator?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The (one-sided) Laplace transform $L(f(t)) = \int_0^{\infty} f(t) e^{-st} \, dt$ has the property that

$$L(t^n) = \frac{n!}{s^{n+1}}$$

so this transform is $f \mapsto s L(f)$, at least formally, and its inverse is given by dividing by $s$ and taking the inverse Laplace transform, again at least formally.